# PYTHON Error: TypeError: 'module' object is notcallable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using this pyAesCrypt library to encrypt/decrypt a password.

Here I define a class User to store the password encrypted in the db, running the application.
Then I need to query the encrypted password from the db and decrypt it, passing it into a variable.
So here's the class I defined:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
#from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
import pyAesCrypt

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///data-users2.sqlite"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    pwd = db.Column(db.LargeBinary(), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, id, username, pwd):
        p = pyAesCrypt(encoding=False)
        self.id = id
        self.username = username
        self.pwd = p.encrypt("password",pwd)
```

Here I query the password from db and decrypt it, but it seems that there is something wrong where I call the module pyAesCrypt, the error is below. Anyone can see any anomaly? If yes could you please edit my code in the correct way? thanks.

```
import pyAesCrypt
        
#get FTP pwd
user = db.session.query(User).filter_by(username="ita_itf").first()
p_decrypt = pyAesCrypt(encoding=False)
DICP_FTP_DESTINATION_PSW = p_decrypt.decrypt("password",user.pwd)
```

ERROR:

```
p_decrypt = pyAesCrypt(encoding=False)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: I have used this guide as a reference, it worked when I have encrypted the pwd in the User class, but it doesn't work when I try to decrypt it from the form.py importing the User class.  https://github.com/ninjatrench/PyAESCrypt

Comment: You can't call the `pyAesCrypt` module because it's not a function. Instead, you should use something like `pyAesCrypt.decryptFile()`.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't really use this to encrypt passwords for the following reasons: (1) it's for things like PDFs, (2) there aren't really any docs so you'd have little support for it and (3) it's mainly for django if anything.

Comment: what if I make a def function in the user class that does the decryption and then I call the function from the form.py?

Comment: I'm just not getting why I cannot call the module pyAesCrypt in my form.py file when I have to do these operation but I can call it in my User class init function, because there it worked perfectly for the encryption,

Comment: so the thing I dont understand because the documentation is very poor, is which is the function in pyAesCrypt I should use to decrypt a string, not binary, not files, just a password string.   DecryptFile() is just for files, decryptStream() only for binary right? so just 0101010101, if I try to just do pyAesCrypt.decrypt(password)  this method doesn't exist.

Comment: It would seem so